# redisson.yaml environment variable

Tags: spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis, redisson

I am using Redisson with Spring-boot and I need to pass in an environment variable to redisson.yaml

**address: "redis://${REDIS_HOST}:6379"**

It's currently not working when passing environment variables.

```
---
singleServerConfig:
  idleConnectionTimeout: 10000
  pingTimeout: 1000
  connectTimeout: 10000
  timeout: 3000
  retryAttempts: 3
  retryInterval: 1500
  password: null
  subscriptionsPerConnection: 5
  clientName: null
  address: "redis://${REDIS_HOST}:6379"
  subscriptionConnectionMinimumIdleSize: 1
  subscriptionConnectionPoolSize: 50
  connectionMinimumIdleSize: 32
  connectionPoolSize: 64
  database: 0
  dnsMonitoringInterval: 5000
threads: 0
nettyThreads: 0
codec: !<org.redisson.codec.JsonJacksonCodec> {}
transportMode: "NIO"
```

Comment: I am facing same issue. Is it working for you now?

Comment: This feature already supported in 3.10.0 version

Comment: I tried that but not able to use env variable. My current version is 3.11.4

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Anybody got it to work?

Answer (score 1):

This feature already supported in 3.10.0 version